# Can't understand values being returned by Facebook Insights API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I don't understand the way the API returns values. Here's a sample of a page_impressions call, with 'week' as the period.

```
"values"=>
[{"end_time"=>"2012-01-08T08:00:00+0000", "value"=>1116},
{"end_time"=>"2012-01-09T08:00:00+0000", "value"=>1171}, 
{"end_time"=>"2012-01-10T08:00:00+0000", "value"=>1175}]
```

It seems that they're showing how many hits I had in the last 7 days up to the date in "end_time", is that correct? If it is, then I don't understand what use this would have, there is a huge overlap in the data.

How can I get the number of impressions of the last weeks instead? And how can I get more than 3 values to display? I really can't understand the logic behind this or how it could be useful.

Comment: Subtraction?  If last week you had 1 visitor and this week you have 5 cumulative visitors then it means you you got 4 visitors over the course of the week.

Comment: It doesn't seem to get me the values of "this week" and "last week" or any sort of weekly period... it still seems to be a daily period, but it gives all impressions from 7 days up to the end_time. There is an overlap of 6 days from one value to the next, of which I'm not understanding the purpose of :(

Comment: I don't understand these new metrics either. When we're looking at stories, what do these mean? "fan":12,"other":2,"page post":2,"user post":2,"mention":1. I can assume what some of these mean, until I look at the Insights on my page, which doesn't correlate to these numbers.

Answer (score 7):

What's happening here is that you're being given the total number of page_impressions for the 7-day period *ending* on each of the dates shown (i.e., how many times was the page seen over the past 7 days assuming the week ended on the end_time? and then on end_time+1? end_time+2)

Facebook is returning three (3) separate readings, presumably so you can spot/review very local trends (e.g., "are my weekly impressions creeping up?) or perhaps because you missed a measurement and want to have values for every day.

To answer your question specifically:

- The 7-day period 2012-01-01 through 2012-01-08 12:00am* had 1,116 impressions.
- The 7-day period 2012-01-02 through 2012-01-09 12:00am* had 1,171 impressions.
- The 7-day period 2012-01-03 through 2012-01-10 12:00am* had 1,175 impressions.

  - As is quoted below, the end_time itself is always midnight in PDT. Thus, an end_time of 2012-01-08 really means the measurement stopped the night before, i.e., at 1 minute past 11:59pm on 2012-01-07.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/:

> The end of the period during which the metrics were collected,
>   expressed as a UNIX time (which should always be midnight, Pacific
>   Daylight Time) or using the function end_time_date() which takes a
>   date string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. Note: If the UNIX time provided is
>   not midnight, Pacific Daylight Time, your query may return an empty
>   resultset. Example: To obtain data for the 24-hour period starting on
>   September 15th at 00:00 (i.e. 12:00 midnight) and ending on September
>   16th at 00:00 (i.e. 12:00 midnight), specify 1284620400 as the
>   end_time and 86400 as the period. Note: end_time should not be
>   specified when querying lifetime metrics.

Comment: So how can you find out how many page impressions you had on each week of the month. Example: let's say I want to analyze month March and display page impressions for the following weeks: 1-7 March 8-15 March, 16-22 March and 21-28 March. How can I accomplish this using facebook data structure ?